# Configuring pgRouting on Win7

Tags: pgrouting

I'm installing pgrouting (ver 1.03_pg-8.4.2) on my windows machine.
I installed PostgreSQL and postgis without any problem, then I downloaded the binary package of pgrouting and I installed it (copy and Paste in postgresql dir). Now I'm trying to configure my first database following the instructions of http://genuchten.blogspot.com/2008/04/untitled.html but I get some errors:

1)

```
psql -U postgres -f ../share/contrib/lwpostgis.sql routing
ERROR: ../share/contrib/lwpostgis.sql No such file or directory
```

2)

```
psql -U postgres -f ../share/contrib/spatial_ref_sys.sql routing
ERROR: ../share/contrib/spatial_ref_sys.sql No such file or directory
```

3)

```
psql -U postgres -f ../share/contrib/routing_core.sql routing
ERROR: incompatible library: librouting.dll: verion mismatch
```

4)

```
psql -U postgres -f ../share/contrib/routing_core_wrappers.sql routing
ERROR: Type "geoms" does not exist
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks Laura

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use instructions for PG 8.2 with an installation of 8.4. That's not going to work. I have instructions for 8.4 on my blog: http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/

In general, be careful with version numbers when dealing with PostgreSQL, PostGIS and pgRouting.

I (Mapperz) verified this morning 06/06/2011 - using Windows 7 Pro (64bit) with Postgres 8.4 and Postgis 1.5 +pgrouting .dlls

(This answer by underdark deserves bonus points!)

[image]

Comment: In truth I'm using PG-9.0

Comment: I don't think there are Windows binaries for 9.0 yet.

Comment: http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows

Comment: I will try with 8.4 anyway!

Comment: I tryed you tutorial but when I execute the routing_core_wrappers query I get this error: ERROR: type "geometry" does not exist

Comment: Yes, there are 9.0 binaries of pg. But no compatible binaries of pgRouting.

Comment: "ERROR: type "geometry" does not exist" sounds like you haven't installed PostGIS.

Comment: And a warning with hte Windows binaries: as they're older, I found them buggy. The only advice I got off the listserver (which I eventually followed) was to switch to Linux/Ubuntu. As you've found, versioning of this entire stack isn't the simplest thing around, and the addition of 64 bit options only complicates things! (I want the latest stuff, 64 bit, and I want it now :-) lol )

Comment: @Mapperz, wouldn't your edit be better as a comment?  @sean can't add pictures with a comment - was a verification more than a comment.

Comment: I installed the 8.4 version for 32 bit!