# Installing TSP functionality on win7

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting

I'm very new to pgRouting!
I installed PostgreSQL 8.4, and pgrouting 1.03 on win7.
I need to solve a TSP problem so I was trying to install the TSL functionality as showen at:
http://www.pgrouting.org/docs/1.x/install.html
but when I type
psql -U postgres -f /usr/share/postlbs/routing_tsp.sql routing
and
psql -U postgres -f /usr/share/postlbs/routing_tsp_wrappers.sql routing
I get an error, as the .sql files can't be found! 
How can I solve?
Where can I download any maps (openstreetmap) to practice?
thanks 
Laura

Comment: You should paste the error message into the body of your question. It will make it easier for others to understand your situation and answer your question.

Comment: The error was: No such file or directory!

Answer (score 1):

This GISe Answer will help

[Configuring pgRouting on Win7](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10637/configuring-pgrouting-on-win7)

Verified by Mapperz but full credit to Underdark.

Comment: If I understand your advice, you are suggesting me to use Ubuntu instead of win! Isn't there any other solution, I need to make my project work on both win and ubuntu!

Comment: You don't need to change to Ubuntu. The instructions are there are designed for Win7.

Comment: Yes, but there's to reference to TSP functionalities!

Comment: In forder /share/contrib of version 1.03 of pgRouting there aren't files for supporting TSP functionality (routing_tsp.sql and routing_tsp_wrapping)  on the other hand these files are included in 1.0 version!

Comment: I had a lot of trouble getting pgRouting to work on Win7. It would run but had a lot of route-specific errors. Basically the built binaries for Windows are a few versions out of date. So you have to build new ones, or use an OS with the latest binaries available (eg. Linux).

Answer (score 0):

You stated you are trying to install this on Win7, right?  It appears the paths you are using (`"/usr/share/postlbs/routing_tsp_wrappers.sql"`) are for a linux install.

You likely need to change your paths to wherever you have downloaded the *.sql files on your computer (ie- `c:\path\to\files\routing_tsp_wrappers.sql`)

Comment: sorry! I pasted from a web site, but on my shell I wrote the correct path!